# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON on storage.setItemSync

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function saveAccounts (accounts, masterPassword) {
    var encryptedAccounts = crypto.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(accounts), masterPassword);
    storage.setItemSync('accounts', encryptedAccounts);
    return accounts;
}
```

Just started to learn javascript/Node. This is giving me TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON on the storage.setItemSync line. Why? Values are passed in correctly as well. I'm following a video tutorial and everything looks typed in correctly. console.log(encryptedAccounts) appears to be encrypted properly.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Node JS with Express Js , we need to write below code to parse request body:-

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't include my requires. I only used crypto and persist here. what got this working for me was calling toString() on encrypedAccounts.